# How to group indices of continuous occurrence of pandas columns values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame like this,

```
df
col1     col2
  1        A
  2        A
  3        A
  4        B
  5        B
  6        A
  7        C
  8        C
  9        C
  10       A
  11       A
  12       A
  13       B
  14       B
  15       A
```

I want to find the indices of col2 values other than A and group it together and put it in a list.

So the list will be having the indices of continuous occurred values other than A

The list will look like,

```
[[3,4],[6,7,8],[12,13]]
```

I could do it using a for loop with a check of previous and next values. But the execution time will be huge. I am looking for pandas shortcut/pythonic way to do it most efficiently.

Comment: Index 3 does have a value `A`, as does index 12.

Comment: @jorijnsmit those are values of `col1`, not indices.

Comment: Oh I see col1 != index? Then the df output is incomplete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Idea is first [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) values for previous `A`, then create consecutive groups by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html), `shift` with [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) and pass to [`DataFrame.groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with `list`:

```
s = df['col2'].shift(-1).ffill()
g = s.ne(s.shift()).cumsum()[s != 'A']
out = df['col1'].groupby(g).apply(list).tolist()
print (out)
[[3, 4], [6, 7, 8], [12, 13]]
```

Answer (score 3):

you can also do it like this

to get index column you may need to call `reset_index`

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([['1', 'A'], ['2', 'A'], ['3', 'A'], ['4', 'B'], ['5', 'B'], ['6', 'A'], ['7', 'C'], ['8', 'C'], ['9', 'C'], ['10', 'A'], ['11', 'A'], ['12', 'A'], ['13', 'B'], ['14', 'B'], ['15', 'A']], columns=('col1', 'col2'))

df2 = (df["col2"] == 'A').cumsum()[df["col2"] != 'A']
df3 = df.groupby(df2).apply(lambda g: list(g.index))
df3.to_list()
```

Comment: Showing the Following Error `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'to_list'`
Pandas Version-`'0.23.3'`

Comment: For the Version `0.23.3`   --> `df3.tolist()` need to use